# Using parcel, how do I deploy my project?

Tags: javascript, parcel

[Forkify](https://github.com/elmi-elmi/demo-js-Fokify-app) (my github link) is a tutorial project I'm working on. To build the dist files, I use `parcel`.

When I use `yarn start` for local deployment, it works correctly, but when I deploy to [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and use `yarn build`, it does not work correctly. The all js code I wrote does not work.

What can I do to fix it?

`package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
"start": "parcel index.html",
"build": "parcel build index.html"}
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: I forked your project and deployed it in less than half a minute: https://blissful-elion-e5eead.netlify.app/ I didn't have to configure anything

Comment: Also, "does not work" is a useless problem description. If you can't tell us how it fails, what answer do you expect?

Comment: @ChrisG no it does not work correctly. please click on button or search...

Comment: That simply means there's a bug in your code. Your question is about deploying it. Judging from the behavior of the app, the form submission isn't prevented and clicking Search reloads the page. This means your code bugs out before the execution hits `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: If "it does not work" is the description of the problem, then "fix it" would be the answer. Be more specific.

Comment: @ChrisG There is no bug. It works correctly on local addresses. However, in netlify, all the JS code does not work.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky There is no bug. It works correctly on local addresse on my laptop. However, in netlify, all the JS code does not work

Comment: The error message in the browser console says that model.js line 136 causes a JSON.parse error. You need `state.bookmarks.push(...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") || "[]"));` because if localStorage is blank you'll be parsing null, which makes your app go bork. This localStorage item already exists in your localhost env, which is why you never noticed this issue.

Comment: I've fixed the bug and updated the app, now I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable Fraction` in view.js line 105. To be fair, this doesn't happen in the local env.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you do indeed have a bug (or a few) in your code.

In `src/js/model.js`, your `init` function assumes that bookmarks are already available in local storage, so a simple work around is to push an empty array if the bookmarks key doesn't exist in local storage.

```
export const init = function () {
  state.bookmarks.push(...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") || "[]"));
};
```